# How do I add an embeddable restricted video from one website to another?

Tags: html, iframe

I want to embed a video on my website from a website but it says "refused to connect" this is the iframe of that video

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" allow="autoplay" scrolling="no" id="match_frame" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" loading="lazy" frameborder="0" src="https://hes-goal.net/frame.php?ch=f1_1&amp;p=12&amp;token=NmQ3NDY1Nzg2YzZhNjczNDZjNmE2OTc4NmU2OTM0Nzk2ZDc2NjIzMTYzMzI2Nzc5NmQ2NDY5Nzk2YjdhNjk3NzZkNmE2MTcxNzM3NTcyNjE2NTZhNjQ2ODY1NzQ3NjMyNmQ3YTc5Njg2NTZhNzU2YQ==&amp;kt=1682763943"></iframe>
```

any solution for this problem let me know.

I tried just publishing iframe code in HTML view but nothing happened solve this problem